# What's actually happening when I convert an int to a string?

Tags: python

I understand it's easy to convert an int to a string by using the built-in method `str()`. However, what's actually happening? I understand it may point to the 
   `__str__` method of the int object but how does it then compute the “informal” string representation? Tried looking at the source and didn't find a lead; any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally the Int object is stored as 2's complement representation like in C (well, this is true if range value allow it, python can automagically convert it to some other representation if it does not fit any more).

Now to get the string representation you have to change that to a string (and a string merely some unmutable list of chars). The algorithm is simple mathematical computing: divide the number by 10 (integer division) and keep the remainder, add that to character code '0'. You get the unit digit. Go on with the result of the division until the result of the division is zero. It's as simple as that.

This approach works with any integer representation but of course it will be more efficient to call the ltoa C library function or equivalent C code to do that if possible than code it in python.

Answer (score 3):

Python repeatedly divides the int by 10 and uses `% 10` to get the decimal digits one by one.

Just to make sure we're looking at the right code, [here's](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ca5431a434d6/Objects/intobject.c#l1171) the function Python 2.7 uses to convert ints to strings:

```
static PyObject *
int_to_decimal_string(PyIntObject *v) {
    char buf[sizeof(long)*CHAR_BIT/3+6], *p, *bufend;
    long n = v->ob_ival;
    unsigned long absn;
    p = bufend = buf + sizeof(buf);
    absn = n < 0 ? 0UL - n : n;
    do {
        *--p = '0' + (char)(absn % 10);
        absn /= 10;
    } while (absn);
    if (n < 0)
        *--p = '-';
    return PyString_FromStringAndSize(p, bufend - p);
}
```

This allocates enough space to store the characters of the string, then fills the digits in one by one, starting at the end. When it's done with the digits, it sticks a `-` sign on the front if the number is negative and constructs a Python string object from the characters. Translating that into Python, we get the following:

```
def int_to_decimal_string(n):
    chars = [None] * enough # enough room for any int's string representation
    abs_n = abs(n)
    i = 0
    while True:
        i += 1
        chars[-i] = str(abs_n % 10) # chr(ord('0') + abs_n % 10) is more accurate
        abs_n //= 10
        if not abs_n:
            break
    if n < 0:
        i += 1
        chars[-i] = '-'
    return ''.join(chars[-i:])
```

Comment: Cool. How did you search for the function in the Python source? I punted and grabbed a generic iota implementation.

Comment: @user2864740: The official Python source code repository is http://hg.python.org/. I searched manually, looking for directories and files that sounded like what I was looking for.

Comment: @user2864740 Here's a direct link to where it's referenced: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c6880edaf6f3/Objects/intobject.c

Answer (score 1):

When you call str() on an object it calls it's classes __ str__ magic method.

for example

```
class NewThing:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

From there you can use the str() method on the object, or use it directly in strings.

```
>> thing = NewThing("poop")
>> print thing
>> poop
```

More info on [magic methods here](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html)

Not sure if this is what you wanted, but I can't comment yet to ask clarifying questions.

Comment: I'm interested in the actual magic behind the _ _ str _ _ method, specifically with the built-in int object. When I call str(6), how is the int object, using _ _ str _ _ , returning a string representation of the number six?